# How to add a new Sink for Cygnus - Fiware?

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I have installed Cygnus and I have it properly running with MYSQL. I would like to send the data which arrive to Cygnus through the notifications from Orion Context Broker, to a REST server.

I need to create a new Sink that processes the data that come from Orion, create the POST requests and run them. In order to do this, I have to create new Java files and I have to put these files in (according to "[Adding new sinks development guide](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/b287a95ecfe73af215cb92aa3ad2af03de3ea834/flume/doc/devel/add_new_sink.md)"):

```
fiware-connectors/flume/src/main/java/es/tid/fiware/fiwareconnectors/cygnus/sinks
```

and:

```
fiware-connectors/flume/src/main/java/es/tid/fiware/fiwareconnectors/cygnus/backends/<my_backend_classes>/
```

But I can not find these places. I installed Cygnus through the `yum install` command, so I do not know how to locate the places where I have to place these new java files.

Could you help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Cygnus by RPM will not install the sources. For that, you have to clone the Github repo (the `git` tool must be installed as well):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus.git
```

That will clone the master branch, which is currently synchronized with the release 0.7.1.

Then, once you have added your new sink, you will have to build and install Cygnus from sources (your altered ones) as explained [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/flume/doc/installation/src_install.md).